# What are the fees involved for a company developing and publising an Android app?

Tags: android, licensing, enterprise

I know that it is $25 for someone to publish to Google play. But I was wondering if it is the same process for a company? Also for a company do any other licensing fees exist?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I believe this is part of the process but if anyone would be kind enough to move me to the correct place I would appreciate it unless we can confirm stephane's answer is correct.

Comment: See Android [Developer Registration](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113468?hl=en) and [Get Started with Publishing](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/start.html). The docs discuss individuals and businesses.

Answer (score 2):

It is the same process. No other fee.

Comment: did someone vote this down because its wrong?

Comment: Not a downvoter, but yes, that might be the cause. It's a misplaced question, at least. I confirm Stephane's words.

Comment: thankyou for confirming I don't know how to move the question.

Comment: Sounds good if no extra fees.